# Vertices NOT scuplting at center of OBJ

Tags: vertices

sorry I'm still new to blender and I've ran into an issue I can't seem to fix.

I was practicing making characters in blender and was able to sculpt and everything without any issues on the first character. However on the second character, it would not let me sculpt the Vertices that were in the center of my object (Where the mirrored object snaps together) It will only move those vertices in edit mode (like in the picture)

You can see at the center top of my object it is coming to a point, that is because the brush was affecting everything but the center vertices when smoothing.

When I switch back over to my first character (both are in the same project), it allows me to sculpt just fine, even at the center of the object.

So this leads me to believe that there is some option that I've looked over or something. Any advice on my situation would be really appreciated as it's a total pain to have to position the vertices manually in edit mode!! Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to have been related to the *Mirror* modifier I was using. When I removed the *Mirror* modifier and used *Symmetrize* instead, the issue was fixed and I am now able to sculpt without any vertices refusing to move.